# High memory usage in Haskell program

Tags: haskell, memory

I am experiencing very high memory consumption in a Haskell program. I have tried to simplify the situation with a short pseudo-Haskell example. In my real program with some test data the LF (logframe) is 24MB after all insertions has been done. In this case the program uses 2GB of memory!

My theory is that this happens because each stage of the final logframe is kept in memory until the function terminates, even though I am only interested in the logframe that has been calculated when the recursion bottoms out. Can someone verify or dismiss that this is the case? And if this is the cause of the problem, can anyone come up with a suggestion for how to structure the program to avoid the heavy use of memory? I have tried to replace the `let` expression with `ex (ex lf1)` but this only yielded a small decrease in memory use.

```
import qualified Data.Map as Map
type LF = Map.Map Int Bool
ex :: various parameters -> LF -> LF
ex case1 lf = lf
ex case2 lf = let lf1 = ex lf 
                  lf2 = ex lf1
              in lf2
ex case3 lf = ex(Map.insert some-int some-bool lf)
```

Really hoping that someone can help! And please let me know if you need some real code, I just thought this was the easiest way to explain and understand the problem :)

**UPDATE**:

- Sorry, the "ex"-function made calls to a function called "closure". This is edited to be recursive calls to "ex" itself.
- I have tried using Data.IntMap.Strict instead with no luck.
- I have pasted some runnable code [here](http://pastebin.com/nYiwfJWQ). It is a regular expression parser which generates an NFA from a regular expression and simulates the input string in the NFA. The relevant code to look at is "simulate" which starts the computation and invokes recursive calls to "closure" and "step". "re2nfa" is just there to be able to test the code - I am 100% sure that this function if the cause of the high memory consumption.
- There are comments at the end of the code with examples of how to call the simulate function.
- I will read up on profiling techniques and see if I can pinpoint the problem.

Comment: Does using `Data.Map.Strict` instead of `Data.Map` make a difference?

Comment: Unrelatedly, you should consider using `Data.IntMap` or `Data.IntMap.Strict`.

Comment: What is `closure`? What are `various parameters`? You should really post actual code that is actually capable of running.

Comment: 1. Have you profiled your code? If not, you should do so. 2. You should post a minimum working example. If there are any obvious "mistakes", they can only be spotted by seeing actual code which will actually run. More importantly, by cutting out code to get a MWE, you may stumble upon the problem yourself.

Comment: In line with a popular old blog post: Don't guess where the memory is going, ask the computer to tell you.  GHC had some great tools. Use them and don't black box debug unless you really need to.

Comment: "My code uses absurd amounts of RAM" usually implies some kind of strictness / laziness bug. You probably have something that builds a giant unevaluated expression that only gets executed right at the end. Without seeing the full code, it's very hard for us to guess where that might be.

Comment: Here is a [useful guide](http://neilmitchell.blogspot.ie/2013/02/chasing-space-leak-in-shake.html) on how to use profiling to find space leaks.